# Can't figure out why code is skipping over if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
let emptyErr = []

if (!(req.files || req.files.image)) {
    emptyErr[0] = ('An image banner is required for a post!')
}

else if (!req.body.title) {
    emptyErr[1] = ('A title is required for a post.')
}

else if (!req.body.body) {
    emptyErr[2] = ('Content is required for a post.')
}

else if (emptyErr.length > 0) {
    req.flash('validationErrors', emptyErr)
    res.redirect('/post/new')
}


let image = req.files.image
```

If I leave the form completely blank, it should check each of these if statements and add a string to the array at the top. Then it would check if there are any elements in the array and redirect to a different page, killing the script. But instead it just skips over the if statements and then complains that the `req.files.image` is null. Which if it was null, it would trigger the first if statement, add an element to the array and hit the last if statement. I'm not too sure why this is happening and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When you use `else if`, it stops as soon as one of the conditions is true, it won't test them all. This is normally used for mutually exclusive conditions. If you want to test all the conditions, just use `if`.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot more sense. So would it be fine to use just if statements for these cases? Or maybe a switch case instead?

Comment: `switch` also only executes the first case that matches. And it's just for doing an equality test with the same expression against different values.

Comment: Just normal `if`s

Comment: Why isn't this obvious from the English meaning of the word "else"? It means "otherwise", so you only do it if the previous condition fails.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want if not else if

by doing what you do, javascript doesn't go inside else if or else if the parent if or if one else if match the condition.

```
let emptyErr = []

if (!(req.files || req.files.image)) {
    emptyErr.push('An image banner is required for a post!')
}

if (!req.body.title) {
    emptyErr.push('A title is required for a post.')
}

if (!req.body.body) {
    emptyErr.push('Content is required for a post.')
}

if (emptyErr.length > 0) {
    req.flash('validationErrors', emptyErr)
    res.redirect('/post/new')
}


let image = req.files.image
```

Also use .push() to add something in the array, else if one if is not correct you will have an incorrect array since index will be empty.

Comment: The first conditional statement is missing an **if**

Comment: yea I'm sorry I edited it

Comment: I don't have access to more code but just for the tips: you can use ```const``` instead of ```let``` for an array when you are using push pop or other methode. ```const``` will restricted you chinging the reference of the array / object but not the modification of it

Comment: Would there be any kind of issue with leaving it as let? Or is it just to make sure you can't overwrite the array later with something by accident?

Comment: @DeveloperLewis there is not an insue ^^, using const will just block you from using ```emptyErr = otherArray ``` but it will accept modification so by using const on an object or array you just explicitly declare the fact the the data can change but not the reference.

this link will explain more than me and with exemple :)

https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_array_const.asp